# setting checked state using attr() vs using prop()

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am trying to check and uncheck boxes when i am clicking through a series of divs. For example I have a list of three divs and each div correspond to one check box. When I select one div I should be checking a box and unchecking the box selected before with the previous click.

Here is my html

```
<div class="trigger">1</div>
<div class="trigger">2</div>
<div class="trigger">3</div>

<input id="one" type="checkbox">
<input id="two" type="checkbox">
<input id="three" type="checkbox">
```

and js

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);
    $('input[type=checkbox]').eq($(this).index('.trigger')).attr('checked', true);
});
```

The process runs fine for the first loop and stops working after the first iteration.But if i use .prop() instead of .attr(), it is working fine.

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
    $('input[type=checkbox]').eq($(this).index('.trigger')).prop('checked', true);
});
```

can anybody explain the reason of this ??

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using `<label for="one">1</label>`? And if you want just one, what's wrong with radio buttons? That way, you don't need jQuery at all!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: Why not use radio button?

Comment: @Kolink i just want to know if i can set checked property using '.attr()' in first iteration, why can't i do the same after first iteration of click events, and why it is not the case when i am using '.prop()'.

Comment: It's not working because you're changing the attribute, not the property, so on the next iteration jQuery will check the property, which hasn't changed, only the attribute has, and it will fail. That's why you should **always use prop() for setting properties**.

Comment: @Nesmar my question not about using buttons, it is about different behaviour of .prop() and .attr() when setting state of checkboxex.

Comment: @adeneo but if in first iterarion, by changing the attribute(not the property) checkbox is in checked state (that means property has change) and same attr() is changing it to false also, why in next iteration by changing the attribute value (in similar manner) it is not changing the property ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following paragraph from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) explains this behaviour:

> Nevertheless, the most important concept to remember about the checked
>   attribute is that it does not correspond to the checked property. The
>   attribute actually corresponds to the defaultChecked property and
>   should be used only to set the initial value of the checkbox. The
>   checked attribute value does not change with the state of the
>   checkbox, while the checked property does. Therefore, the
>   cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is
>   to use the property.

Answer (score 1):

There is a significant difference between `.prop()` and `.attr()`

**Attributes vs. Properties**

---

The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. **Before jQuery 1.6**, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. **As of jQuery 1.**6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.

For example, selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName, nodeType, ownerDocument, defaultChecked, and defaultSelected should be retrieved and set with the .prop() method. **Prior to jQuery 1.6, these properties were retrievable with the .attr() method, but this was not within the scope of attr.** These do not have corresponding attributes and are only properties.

*NOTE:For more info check offical jQuery site,*http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Happy Coding :)